# Calculating determinants from matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant, circulant-matrices, permutation-matrices

> 1. $[10$ points $]$ Let $P$ be a $n \times n$ matrix, where the entries of of $P=\left(p_{i j}\right)$ are as follows:
>    $$
>    p_{i j}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}
>    1 \text { if } i=j+1 \\
>    1 \text { if } i=1, j=n \\
>    0 \text { otherwise. }
>    \end{array}\right.
>    $$
>    Namely,
>    $$
>    P=\left[\begin{array}{ccccc}
>    0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 1 \\
>    1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
>    0 & 1 & \cdots & 0 & 0 \\
>    \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
>    0 & \cdots & \cdots & 1 & 0
>    \end{array}\right]
>    $$
>    Calculate the determinants $\operatorname{det}(P), \operatorname{det}(I+5 P),$ and $\operatorname{det}\left(I+3 P+4 P^{2}\right)$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.

[Transcribed from this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZiqF.png)

I solved this and got $\det(P) = 0+0+0+....+ 1(1) = 1$. So, $\det(P) = 1$. Now, we already know that $\det(I) = 1$ and $\det(I+5P) = \det(I) + 5 \det(P) = 1 + 5\times 1 = 1 + 5 = 6$, and
$\det(I+3P+4P^2) = \det(I) + 3\det(P) + 4\det(P^2) = 1 + 3\times1 + 4\times0 = 1 + 3 = 4$ since $\det(P^2) = 0$.

Is this correct? Kindly check and let me know if there are any problems. Thanks a lot in advance for your help.

Comment: Note that $\det(A+B)$ need not be equal to $\det(A)+\det(B)$.

Comment: @AnuragA is it that $det(A.B) = Det(A).Det(B)$ ? I dont know where I am going wrong.

Comment: Yes $\det(AB)=\det(A) \cdot \det(B)$.

Comment: but that won't help me either because I don't find any applications of it here.

Comment: I've transcribed the image for you, but please do it yourself next time. If you're lazy to do it by hand, you can use the mathpix software to do almost all the work (google)

Comment: In addition, seeing the [10 marks], I hope you're not getting someone else to do an assessed assignent for you

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am sorry for that, and I am not getting anyone to do it for me. I did it and I got the results that I wrote below that picture while posting this. I was wondering that I am correct but unfortunately I am not, therefore I needed help from someone.

Answer (score 4):

For $\det(I+5P)$. Consider the following:
$$
\det(I+5P)=
\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0& \ldots &0 &5\\
5&1&0& \ldots &0 &0\\
0&5&1& \ldots &0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0&0&0& \ldots &5 &1\\
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Expand (using Laplace's cofactor expansion) about the first row to get
\begin{align*}
\det(I+5P)&=1 \, \underbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&0& \ldots &0 &0\\
5&1&0& \ldots &0 &0\\
0&5&1& \ldots &0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0&0&0& \ldots &5 &1\\
\end{vmatrix}}_{\text{lower triangular}}+(-1)^{n+1}5 \, \underbrace{\begin{vmatrix}
5&1&0& \ldots &0 &0\\
0&5&1& \ldots &0 &0\\
0&0&5& \ldots &0 &0\\
\vdots & \vdots &\vdots & \ldots & \vdots & \vdots\\
0&0&0& \ldots &0 &5\\
\end{vmatrix}}_{\text{upper triangular}}\\
&=1(1)+(-1)^{n+1}5^{n}\\
&=\color{red}{1-(-5)^n}.
\end{align*}
Note here we have used the fact that for upper and lower triangular matrices the determinant is the product of the diagonal entries.

In case, you have studied eigenvalues and/or if you realize that $P$ is a **permutation matrix**, then it can help in approaching the remaining determinant.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me on this...I did find the other one. P is a permutation matrix and $P^2$ is a product of 2 permutation matrices which results in a permutation matrix again based on whether n is even or odd. If its odd, its +1 and if n is even, its -1 and you solve that accordingly. I am done with it. Appreciate your help and support.

Answer (score 0):

Your argument isn't correct. Unless the matrix is $1\times1$, the determinant function is not an additive. You cannot argue that $\det(I+5P)=\det(I)+\det(5P)$ without any justification (and in fact, you cannot justify that because the two sides are not equal). Also, $\det(5P)$ is equal to $5^n\det(P)$, not $5\det(P)$. The way you handled $\det(I+3P+4P^2)$ is wrong too for the same reason.

For any nonzero polynomial $g$, by inspecting the entries on the first row of $g(P)$, one may argue that $g(P)\ne0$ when $\deg(g)<n$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $P$ has degree $n$. As $P^n=I$, the minimal polynomial of $P$ must be $f(x)=x^n-1$. Hence the characteristic polynomial of $P$ is also $f$, and
\begin{aligned}
\det(P)&=(-1)^n\det\left(0I-P\right)=(-1)^nf(0),\\
\det(I+5P)&=(-5)^n\det\left(-\frac15I-P\right)=(-5)^nf\left(-\frac15\right).
\end{aligned}
By factorising $1+3x+4x^2$ into a product of two linear factors, one can also obtain $\det(I+3P+4P^2)$ in a similar way.